# Angularjs initialize $on in other controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-routing

i have a normal navbar with a menuController, this is the parent.

in this menuController is a method 'sendData()' with a broadcast method and a location call "$location.path('/page2')" which redirects me to page 2 .. the sendData() Method is triggered if i click on a link on my navbar.

the broadcast method should then send an event with some data to my other controller on page2.

In my page2 controller is the $on method which should recieve the event.. but the problem is, at this time i clicked on the navbar link which send the broadcast.. the controller on page 2 is not initialized. this means the $on method is also not initialized and so i can`t recieve the event..

so what can i do to solve this problem?  before i send the broadcast event, the $on mehtod in my page2 controller must be initialized. how can i do that ?
and i use a routeProvider for initializing my controllers..

```
$routeProvider.when('/page2', {templateUrl: 'partials/page2.html', controller: 'page2Controller'});
```

Comment: Generally, and particularly in this case, you're better off using a service to communicate between controllers rather than Angular events. From one controller or directive (ie your navbar), you can call a service and place some data there for your other controller(s) to collect when they initialize.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is create a `service|factory` and initialize or set the data on your service when your **page2** is initialized it will pull the information from the `service|factory`.